# Polymorphic association and foreign key reference can reference same table. How do I make a new object?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

A simplified example of what I have is

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bananas, as: :bananable, dependent: destroy
  has_many :bananas
end

class Orange < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bananas, as: :bananable, dependent: destroy
end

class Banana < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bananable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :apple
end
```

So a Banana may belong_to either an Apple or an Orange as bananable, but will belong to an Apple through a foreign key relation regardless.  This may seem a bit forced in the context of fruit, but the actual models are quite complex, so I simplified things.  Basically the polymorphic association defines the scope the Banana exists inside, but the Banana is part of an Apple regardless of it's scope.

The issue I am having is when I try to create a new banana.  For example:

```
@Apple.bananas.new(valid_params)
```

This sets the apple_id foreign key column in the bananas table, but does not set the polymorphic association columns (bananable_id and bananable_type).  The only way I have found to set both is to create a new banana as above, then manually set the polymorphic association columns before saving.

Is there a better way to do this?

Perhaps something like:

```
@banana = @Apple.bananas.new(valid_params)
@Apple.bananables << @banana
```

or for oranges

```
@banana = @Apple.bananas.new(valid_params)
@Orange.bananables << @banana
```

The best I have come up with so far is

```
@banana = @Apple.bananas.new(valid_params)
if params.has_key?(:orange_id)
  @banana.bananable = @orange
else
  @banana.bananable = @apple
end
@banana.save
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the :inverse_of attribute in your Banana model. I know that the Rails docs say that this doesn't have any effect, but it does seem to have done something to help in my previous code. You might try, though I make no guarantees.

```
belongs_to :bananable, polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :bananas
```

From my notes, this helps Rails understand the relationship between the  association and its inverse, which for me allowed it to correctly identify item type.

As another option, be sure to check that validations are not breaking your  database updates. For testing, I had to use save! to ensure exceptions were thrown and I could catch where hidden issues were breaking my associations.

Comment: It didn't work in this situation, but it can have an effect under certain circumstances.  [See here under "Setting Inverses"](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Bi-directional+associations)

Comment: @Kittenmittons what are your actual class names? Could there be an issue with the naming of the classes that is obscured by your 'fruit' example? Also, which database are you using? In the past I had some issues with Postgres and case sensitivity after overriding a method for display purposes, where MySQL worked fine. Probably worth checking the exact SQL in the debug log to see if there is a database level issue, or something happening higher up the stack.

Comment: Banana: Sharedstep, Apple: Version, Orange: Feature.  Using MSSQL

Comment: @Kittenmittons - I think I'm out of suggestions. If you haven't already, try creating a test  Rails app with just the basic polymorphic models and migrations needed to demonstrate the issue. Hopefully this will help you identify if there is an issue with an overridden method, a failing validation, or some other hidden issue. Feel free to post any results and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First of all clearly understand the polymorphic association. Ruby on Rails Guide states `“with polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association”`.

I am sure that you don't need two association to the same table. Whenever you create a `banana` through `apple`, `bananable_id` and `bananable_type` won't be set because the rails find the association through `apple_id` and it doesn't bother about any other associations.

As far as I know, you are unnecessarily complicating your models.
I bet the below association can get all the functionalities you need.

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bananas, as: :bananable, dependent: destroy
end

class Orange < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bananas, as: :bananable, dependent: destroy
end

class Banana < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bananable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Incase you have any valid points to say why you need two associations for same model, please comment.

Comment: That's not how polymorphic associations work.  They allow the belonging model to belong to different types of models.  They cannot belong to multiple models at the same time.  If you look at the columns created in a SQL database when you use the design you have suggested, you will see that the bananas table will have 2 columns for the polymorphic association: :bananable_type and :bananable_id.  This only allows for a single owner (e.g. bananable_type: "Orange", bananable_id: 55, means the Banana belongs to the Orange with id 55)

Comment: @Kittenmittons I know what you commented. You have misunderstood. I pointed out that two associations to same model i.e. 
`class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bananas, as: :bananable, dependent: destroy
  has_many :bananas
end`
is unnecessary. Why does he need two `has_many` for `bananas` ???

Comment: @Kittenmittons With your question, I assume that your DB contains all three fields `apple_id` `bananable_id` and `bananable_type`. If that is the case, when you try creating `banana` through `apple` I think rails finds the association through `apple_id` first and it never bothers finding any other associations(i.e. polymorphic association). So `bananable_type` and `bananable_id` are not created.

Comment: I explained why briefly in my question.  The short of it is that the polymorphic association is used for scoping uniqueness while the Id is used for versioning. It is not up to me as it is a work project